# Managed Metadata Richtext Search Result

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

I have an custom list. This list contains some columns. One of them is an Textcolumn that can hold richtext inside.

Now I created a SearchDisplay Template.

I saw the crwaled property and mapped it to an Managed Metadata Property (Type: Text).

But when I got the results, it display me only the plaintext result not the Richtext result.

How can I get the richtext (HTML?) result, to display it into the result page.

Comment: Please refer a similar problem here. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114405/rich-text-column-contents-returned-as-plain-text-in-search

Comment: Thx that helped me out.